# Mean value over multiple dimensions

Tags: matlab

I have  a multi dimensional matrix with pixel data. The first two are x and y, then follow different dimensions, z and t.

The goal is to average over multiple dimensions. To for example get a plot of mean intensity vs z, or calculate further with mean pixel values in z and time.
How to do this, while also maintaining the original matrix dimension? I generated an example:

```
%generate some demo data
A=ones([3 2 4 5]);
for ct = 1:4
    A(:,:,ct,:)=A(:,:,ct,:)*ct;
end
for ct = 2:5
    A(:,:,:,ct)=A(:,:,:,ct)*ct;
end
%t=1,z=1 => x and y all 1
%t=2,z=3 => x and y all 6
```

To do it I wrote a function:

```
function [M_out] = meanD(M_in,D,argin)
%takes the mean over the dimensions in D
if nargin<2||isempty(D),M_out=mean(M_in);return;end
if nargin<3||isempty(argin),argin='default';end
if length(unique(D))~=length(D),error('double dimensions');end
S = size(M_in);
N = prod(S(D));
if D(end)>length(S),error('dimension does not exist');end
if length(D)==length(S),M_out=mean(M_in(:),argin);end
dims = 1:length(S);
dims = [D,dims(~ismember(dims,D))];
S=S(dims);
M_out = permute(M_in,dims); % move the requested dimensions to the beginning
M_out = reshape(M_out,[N,S(1+length(D):end)]);
M_out = mean(M_out,argin);
```

However

```
meanD(A,[1,2])
>> average over x and y. [1 2 3 4 5; 2 4 6 8 10; 3 6 9 12 15; 4 8 12 16 20]
```

So the values are correct, but in a 1x4x5 matrix. I need them to be in a 1x1x4x5 matrix.

```
meanD(A,[3,4])
>> [7.5 7.5 ; 7.5 7.5 ; 7.5 7.5]
```

This one is correct correct, since it needs to be a 3x2x1x1 matrix and matlab should remove trailing singleton dimensions.

Comment: If you need weird sizes (such as 1x1x4x5) just make sure you don't squeeze! The job of squeeze is literaly removing singelton dimensions

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot to update the code. `squeeze` indeed removes a dimension, but `reshape` did aswel. I admit the `1x1x4x5` is a bit strange, but often quite usefull if you want to subtract matrices. In this case a `3x2x1x5` for example if you want to subtract the mean z-value. from all pixels and timepoints.

Comment: That is the job of `bsxfun`!

Comment: Yes, but only if you have one dimension to average over. The mean pixel value for each z and t dimension is a `1x1x4x5` that can be subtracted from the original `3x2x4x5`

Comment: Why not just `mean(mean(A,D(1)),D(2))` ? And if you need more general, `for ii=1:length(D);    A=mean(A,D(ii));   end`

Comment: @Jon when there are NaN's in the matrix it gives a biased result. Concider a column with 9 NaN's and 1 value of 2. In the row mean that mean column value of 2 is weight by the same weight as the next column that might be the mean of 10 values. But your method does keep the proper dimensions.

Comment: Is that true even with the `'omitnan'` flag though?

Comment: Yes. Works per dimension. [1 nan 2 ; 1 2 3] -> [1 2 2.5] -> 1.833, where it should be just 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a final `reshape` as follows:

```
s = size(M_in);
s(ismember(1:ndims(M_in), D)) = 1;
M_out = reshape(M_out, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that as of Matlab R2018b, this functionality provided by the above `meanD` is available in Matlab natively:

> M = mean(A,vecdim) computes the mean based on the dimensions specified in the vector vecdim. For example, if A is a matrix, then mean(A,[1 2]) is the mean of all elements in A, since every element of a matrix is contained in the array slice defined by dimensions 1 and 2.

This will not work with Matlab R2018a or earlier versions, however.